# Java Stream#map apparently doesn't work anymore

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am currently working on a deserialization of multiple processes within a single object.
The thing is that I pass a Collection as the *object* parameter. Everything works fine -> I get the regular output of:

*Deserialize object [testCollection] with type argument java.lang.String

Object is collection.*

Now, throughout the mapping procedure in a Stream, I should get the output
of every element within the *object* that has been identified as a collection, as wanted.
So I should get the following output:

*Deserialize object [testCollection] with type argument java.lang.String

Object is collection.

Deserialize object testCollection with type argument java.lang.String*
as *testCollection* is the only element within the collection.
But I don't get any input afterwards. I tried printing every element in forEach, which actually worked. But mapping doesn't.

Maybe someone knows how I could fix this problem, maybe I am too tired of seeing the issue :D

```java
    @Recursive("_, Collection")
    public static Object prepareDeserialization(Class<?> typeClass, Object object) {
        System.out.printf("Deserialize object %s with type argument %s%n", object, typeClass);
        //Check if the object could be a collection
        if (isCollection(objectClass)) {
            System.out.println("Object is collection.");
            return (((Collection<?>) object)).stream()
                    .map((e) -> prepareDeserialization(typeClass, e));
        }
```

Comment: Ermm ... I'm afraid that both your code AND your explanation of what it is supposed to do AND your description of the expected and actual outputs are all pretty much incomprehensible.  Perhaps you should provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hey there yeah sorry. I already fixed the problem. I'll explain in more detail next time, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `map` is lazy, in the sense that it won't produce you a final result. It will produce a new `Stream`, that once *consumed* will `map` its input with the function.

The keyword here is *consumed*.

In a `Stream` you consume it with the method `collect`.
The simples example would be this:

```java
if (isCollection(objectClass)) {
    System.out.println("Object is collection.");
    return (((Collection<?>) object)).stream()
            .map((e) -> prepareDeserialization(typeClass, e))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // <- now your result is a list, that will contain the "mapped" objects
}
```